# Trocar o tema de um site

Tags: javascript, html, css

preciso criar temas para o meu site, ao entrar no site a pessoa clica em um botão para trocar para o tema escolhido, mas ao clicar no botão tem que trocar além do css, as imagens que contém no site (que no caso são as imagens dos botões do menu), é que nem vc usar joomla ou wordpress e trocar o tema do site, só que o problema é que não posso usar um CMS para fazer o site, então tenho que fazer tudo na mão, mas até agora não encontrei nada que me ajudasse a trocar o tema do site todo com um clique. Alguém sabe me dizer como eu posso fazer isso?
Obrigada!

Coloquei os códigos e imagens zipados no dropbox, acho que assim dá pra entender melhor o que preciso....
[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/quu62ryyah6ylrj/skeleton.zip)

Comment: Oi, Tassiana, bem vinda ao [pt.so]. Por favor, forneça mais detalhes sobre o código que usa no seu site. Usa algum banco de dados? Você pode **[edit]** a pergunta sempre que precisar adicionar informações.

Comment: A resposta depende de como você implementa o "tema" no seu site, por exemplo, ele possui imagens? Ou só mudariam as cores? O código está todo no CSS? Ou teria que mudar algum código também na própria página (trocar tags de imagem, por exemplo, etc)? Etc...

Comment: Legal sua edição, mas só mais um detalhe: é melhor incluir *aqui* o código relevante. Confira o guia sobre como criar um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); é uma técnica bem útil para ajudar na resolução de problemas.

Comment: @Kazzkiq sim, além do css tem imagens pelo site que precisam ser modificadas, eu editei minha pergunta e coloquei o link para baixar no dropbox a pasta de arquivos zipada do site que estou fazendo

Answer (score 3):

Coloque as imagens de cada tema em uma pasta separada.

No javascript crie uma função que percorra todas as imagens do site, que possuí uma determinada classe (no caso do exemplo a classe .imagens-relativas) e envie como parâmetro o nome da pasta do tema determinado.

Abaixo segue um script (jQuery) que percorre todas as imagens de determinada classe:

```
$(".imagens-relativas").each(function(index){
    var src = $(this).attr("src")
    var photoName = src.substr(src.lastIndexOf("/"));
    $(this).attr("src", pastaTema+"/"+photoName)
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Não seria melhor colocar as regras de imagens dos botões no CSS também? Dessa maneira, além de trocar o CSS, você troca todas as propriedades de seu site inteiro, podendo fazer vários temas.

Mas se você quiser manter as propriedades inline(na tag), seria uma ótima idéia usar JavaScript. Prefira JavaScript puro e use classes em suas tags HTML.

[Exemplo em JS (muito básico, muda as cores de texto)](http://jsfiddle.net/9ssyh5yh/1/)

Comment: sim, eu quero usar javascript para trocar o css e as imagens do site, mas preciso trocar tudo isso clicando em um botão para selecionar o tema, aí clica e troca toda a "cara" do site inclusive as páginas internas

Comment: Acho que seria interessante você começar a estudar um pouco de jQuery, ou melhor ainda, alguma linguagem de programação para web(PHP ou Java). Trocar CSS por JavaScript puro(ou até mesmo com jQuery) é trabalhoso, e geralmente não vale a pena o esforço.

Comment: sim sim, tenho ciência disso, o problema é que o tempo que preciso para fazer isso é curto, tenho prazo =/, sou web designer front-end, e estou começando agora a fazer back-end

Comment: Então baseie-se na solução do @AndréCastro, é uma das formas mais rápidas para mudar estilos de componentes. Não posso te ajudar muito pois só sei como mudar folhas de estilo inteiras pelo PHP ou Java.

Comment: sim, estou tentando desenvolver uma solução em cima do que ele me indicou, mas ainda não consegui fazer funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar jQuery para adicionar e remover tags CSS:

Veja [este exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e1abma08/):

```html
<style id="css">
body { font-size: 7pt; }
</style>

Um texto qualquer.

<button id="botao">Clique-me!</button>
```

E o Javascript:

```
var css = '<style id="css2">body{ font-size: 32pt; }</style>';

$("#botao").click(function() {
  $("#css").remove();
  $("head").append(css);
});
```

Ao clicar no botão a *tag* antiga é removida e uma nova é adicionada.

**Dica**: Ao invés do que fiz acima você pode apontar para um CSS externo

```js
$("head").append('<link href="MeuCSSExterno.css"></link>');
```

Comment: me ajudaria muito isso se fosse só o css a mudar =/